# How to combine and if statement with a formula to concatenate?

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

Trying to combine two formulas together but can't figure out how to get them to work. The concatenate formula is

```
=IF(OR(UPPER(D6)="",UPPER(D6)="N"),A6,A6&" - "&D6)
```

The formula was created so that if "Y" was entered in a checkbox (yes), then it would combine two different parts to create a result in a separate box. If "N" is entered then it would not concatenate.

The formula was originally

```
=IF(OR((AND((A6<>""),(D6<>""))),(AND((B6<>""),(D6<>"")))),IF(A6="",B6,A6),"")
```

I'm trying to figure out how to put a concatenate formula somewhere in this one, haven't had any luck so far.. Thank you.

Comment: can you share sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Most Excel worksheet formulas are not case sensitive, so you don't need UPPER().

Your original formula has a logic error. It can only return TRUE if A is NOT blank. But in the TRUE part, you have another IF statement that is only TRUE if A6 **is** blank. That situation never happens.

How complicated the formula will be depends on what the logic is. If the result should always be one thing for "n" or a blank input, and another thing for a "y" input, maybe you only need to test for "y" instead of testing for "" and "n".

```
=if(and(A1="y",B1="y"),X&" - "&Y,X)
```

If that does not answer your question, please edit your question, provide a data sample and the desired result and explain the logic. Then post a comment, so people get alerted about the update.